# How to show a $\mathbb{C}$-representation is not the complexification of a $\mathbb{R}$-representation?

Tags: representation-theory

For a homework problem in a course of representation theory, I have to show that some complex representation of a group $G$ is not the complexification of the real one. I don't really understand how to do this. Do I have to show that there exist no basis of the vector space such that the representation expressed in that basis gives always real matrices or what else?

Comment: "Do I have to show that there exist no basis of the vector space such that the representation expressed in that basis gives always real matrices" -- Yes, that's one way to rewrite your question. Of course, it's not how it's usually done in practice. Do you know the theory of the Frobenius indicator?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Yes, in fact the exercise I'm trying to do is subdivided into 2 parts. The second part's goal is to show it using the Frobenius indicator.